# How to count similar objects in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, count

I've been trying to do my thesis in OpenCV using webcam for a live video and python. One of my problems for a few weeks now, is the fact that i cant enumerate similar objects.
For example i have managed to count the number of the objects in the following picture, but the thing is that, i cant display the number of squares(square1, square2, square3), the number of circles(circle1, circle2) and the number of triangles(triangle1)...(lets skip the fact that there's a rectangle and an elipse here and just name them, square and cirle).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyps8.png)

Any idea on how should i proceed with my code?
Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go through this link, on how to ask questions : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Have you done a Google search? Always try that before asking questions here. Does this help -- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: I've done quite an extensive search on Google before posting my first question here and i have been familiar with Mr Adrian Rosebrock's work. He's very helpfull.
Although his post doesnt answer my question. I want to know the number on squares, the number of circles and the number of triangles on the picture. 
Thank you for your time.